# VPN provide privacy, but does it provide security as well like virus checking?

Tags: vpn

I have a question in my exam last week on Network Security whether a malware can be transferred over a VPN tunnel?

My answer was YES, since VPN only provide encryption, and makes sure data travel from point A to point B encrypted.

What I understand is, a generic VPN will encrypt any kind of data, even if its a virus or a malware, and transfer it securely over a network.

Once data is encrypted, even VPN cannot scan it or perform any checking on that data unless it is reached to point B where it is decrypted.

I am still confused if I was correct.

Answer (score 3):

While it is possible that some product exists that attempts to do virus detection, a VPN alone does not provide any assurances regarding the content that flows through it. You are right that the VPN may be encrypted (a VPN doesn't need encryption to be a VPN, as its main use is to tunnel in to remote networks, although nearly all VPNs are encrypted), and thus network IDS systems will typically not be able to analyze the contents. That said, sensors could be placed on the VPN server to inspect traffic after encryption terminates.

So yes, it is certainly possible for malware to travel/spread over a VPN. It's just data like anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer was correct.

What was a bit over simplified is your bit on what a VPN provides. As a tutor I often advice students to draft their answers carefully. State your assumption (i.e. IPsec VPN in tunnel mode) and then explain it from there. Sure, a VPN provides an encrypted channel, but it does also authenticate the communicating parties and offer integrity protection.

But don't let my answer discourage you, I don't know how your school grades and I don't know how many points you could have scored!